# How do I select values of different ForeignKeyIDs of the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

Its been a while since I did msSql, so can anyone please remind me how do I select values of different ForeignKeyIDs?

What I want is to select values greater than 10 when the ForeignKeyID is 1; then I want to select values greater than 20 when the ForeignKeyID is 2; and value greater than 30 when the ForeignKeyID is 3 and so on...

I know for a fact that the following execution doesnt work because I get an empty result whereas I see in my table (filled with thousands of records) that my previously mentioned conditions exist.

```
SELECT [ForeignKeyID]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [tblMyTable]
  where (ForeignKeyID = 1 and Value > 10) and (ForeignKeyID = 2 and Value > 20) and (ForeignKeyID = 3 and Value > 30)
```

**I think I'm not putting the brackets correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong logical operator. The relationship between each pair of conditions in the braces should be `or`, not `and`:

```
SELECT [ForeignKeyID]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [tblMyTable]
 WHERE (ForeignKeyID = 1 AND Value > 10) OR
       (ForeignKeyID = 2 AND Value > 20) OR
       (ForeignKeyID = 3 AND Value > 30)
```

Note that this condition could be simplified considerably with some mathematical trickery:

```
SELECT [ForeignKeyID]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [tblMyTable]
 WHERE ForeignKeyID IN (1, 2, 3) -- Or any other value you want to allow
       AND Value > (10 * ForeignKeyValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a sample table and make a generic query which will append the Where classes based on ForiegnKeyID and Value :)

```
Create table Mytemp
(
ForeignKeyID int,
[Value] int
)

Insert into Mytemp values (1,10)
Insert into Mytemp values (2,20)
Insert into Mytemp values (3,30)
Insert into Mytemp values (4,40)
Insert into Mytemp values (5,50)
Insert into Mytemp values (6,60)
Insert into Mytemp values (7,70)
Insert into Mytemp values (8,80)


DECLARE @value INT
Declare @FKey INT

Declare @SQL varchar(max)
Declare @Where varchar(max)

Set @Where=''

set @SQL='SELECT [ForeignKeyID] ,[Value] FROM Mytemp'


DECLARE @db_cursor CURSOR
SET @db_cursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT [ForeignKeyID] ,[Value] FROM Mytemp
OPEN @db_cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @db_cursor INTO @FKey, @value
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    If @Where=''
        set @Where='(ForeignKeyID = '+Convert(varchar,@FKey) +' AND Value > '+Convert(varchar,@value) +')'
    Else
        set @Where=@Where+ ' OR '  +'(ForeignKeyID = '+Convert(varchar,@FKey) +' AND Value > '+Convert(varchar,@value) +')'



FETCH NEXT
FROM @db_cursor INTO @FKey, @value
END
CLOSE @db_cursor
DEALLOCATE @db_cursor


set @SQL=@SQL+' Where ' + @Where
Print (@SQL)
Exec (@SQL)

Drop table Mytemp
```

Comment: I forgot to add the resultant query, It will automatically generate below query with above mentioned query generator and then you can execute it. It will automatically append conditions based on value and foreignkeyid.

SELECT [ForeignKeyID] ,[Value] FROM Mytemp Where (ForeignKeyID = 1 AND Value > 10) OR (ForeignKeyID = 2 AND Value > 20) OR (ForeignKeyID = 3 AND Value > 30) OR (ForeignKeyID = 4 AND Value > 40) OR (ForeignKeyID = 5 AND Value > 50) OR (ForeignKeyID = 6 AND Value > 60) OR (ForeignKeyID = 7 AND Value > 70) OR (ForeignKeyID = 8 AND Value > 80)